# Why Can't I Create a VirtualBox VM Using Vagrant?

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, hyper-v, vagrant

I recently bought a book called: DevOps for the Desparate and cannot get past chapter 1 exercises to create a VM in Oracle Virtual Box.

In the initial set-up phase for chapter 1, I am creating:

1. A Hyper-V Ubuntu VM
2. In the Ubuntu VM, I am creating another VM in Oracle VirtualBox using Vagrant

I've gone through the exercises multiple times now and not having much luck since when I get to the command that creates the VM using

```
vagrant up
```

The creation fails.

I've tried the following OS's

1. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
2. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
3. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

[image]

This was not in the instructions, but when the Hyper-V image is created, I resized the hard drive to 100GB in Hyper-V setting since I kept running out of space when I ran:

`$vagrant up`

After I resized the hard drive in Hyper-V, I discovered that I also needed to resize the Linux partition which I did using:

`growpart`

[image]

All of the other steps I completed successfully, IE:

Page xiv
`Set-VMProcessor -VMName 'Ubuntu 20.04 LTS' -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true`

Page xxi
`$git clone https://github.com/bradleyd/devops_for_the_desperate/`

Page 4
Installed Vagrant

Page 7
Installed Ansible

When I get to Page 9, this fails:

```
$ vagrant up
```

I've been getting different errors, but now I am getting this one:

```
$ vagrant up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...

==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/focal64'...

==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...

==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/focal64' version '20230719.0.0' is up to date...

==> default: Setting the name of the VM: dftd

==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...


**There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant for controlling     VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.


Command: ["hostonlyif", "ipconfig", "vboxnet2", "--ip", "172.28.128.1", "--netmask", "255.255.255.0"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) - Access denied (extended info not     available)

VBoxManage: error: Context: "EnableStaticIPConfig(Bstr(pszIp).raw(), Bstr(pszNetmask).raw())" at line 242 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp**
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried just making an Ubuntu Virtualbox VM without some other added on layer of tools? It's pretty easy.

Comment: Yes, just tried with VirtualBox using Ubuntu 20.04. 
Doesn't work.
When I start the image, it hangs with a message saying kworker exited with preempt count 2

Comment: I use them all the time. Do you have virtualization enabled in your BIOS/EFI? Did you provide adequate resources (CPU, RAM) for the VM?

Comment: Virtualization enabled
Base Memory 9216MB - 1 CPU

Comment: Set CPU=4.  Still no good

Comment: Again, my laptop is Windows 11 Pro - 1 CPU/14 Cores/20 Logical processors->Within Windows 11 Pro, I running an Ubuntu Linux 22.04 VM in Hyper V that has 11 virtual processors->Within the Hyper-V VM I am running an Ubuntu Linux 22.04 VM Oracle Virtual Box VM that has 5 Processors.  Hope that helps

Comment: It's clear you've plety of spare oomph in the hardware. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: So since I was striking out with creating the VBox image, I went back to trying $vagrant up.  It seems to be hanging here:

==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /home/user/devops_for_the_desperate/vagrant